# Retrieve email FacebookSDK and Swift

Tags: facebook, swift, facebook-login

I'm successfully implemented facebook login in my app, but I'm not able to query/retrieve the email address from the user.

I have the following code:

```
import UIKit

class testViewController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil)
        {
            // User is already logged in, do work such as go to next view controller.

            // Or Show Logout Button
            let loginView : FBSDKLoginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
            self.view.addSubview(loginView)
            loginView.center = self.view.center
            loginView.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
            loginView.delegate = self
            self.returnUserData()
        }
        else
        {
            let loginView : FBSDKLoginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
            self.view.addSubview(loginView)
            loginView.center = self.view.center
            loginView.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
            loginView.delegate = self
        }

    }

    // Facebook Delegate Methods

    func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {
        println("User Logged In")

        if ((error) != nil)
        {
            // Process error
        }
        else if result.isCancelled {
            // Handle cancellations
        }
        else {
            // If you ask for multiple permissions at once, you
            // should check if specific permissions missing
            if result.grantedPermissions.contains("email")
            {
                // Do work
            }

            self.returnUserData()
        }

    }

    func loginButtonDidLogOut(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
        println("User Logged Out")
    }

    func returnUserData() {
        let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: nil)
        graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in

            if ((error) != nil)
            {
                // Process error
                println("Error: \(error)")
            }
            else
            {
                println("fetched user: \(result)")
                let userName : NSString = result.valueForKey("name") as! NSString
                println("User Name is: \(userName)")
                let userEmail : NSString = result.valueForKey("email") as! NSString
                println("User Email is: \(userEmail)")
            }
        })
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

And the println output:

```
fetched user: {
    id = 808101565906152;
    name = "Marcelo Pontes Machado";
}
```

When I try to display the email I got a nill value.

I think the code is right, maybe some SDK that I miss to import?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Put the fields you want back from the Graph request in your parameters

```
FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"id,email,name,picture.width(480).height(480)"]).startWithCompletionHandler({
```

Because the Graph API may sometimes only return a minimum amount of information unless otherwise requested.

Comment: Worked! I used without the .startWithCompletionHandler({, is this correct too ? thanks @thefredelement

Answer (score 3):

1. In Swift

   ```
   if((FBSDKAccessToken.current()) != nil)
   {
       FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"]).start(completionHandler:
           { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
               if (error == nil)
               {
                   //everything works print the user data
                   //                        print(result!)
                   if let data = result as? NSDictionary
                   {
                       let firstName  = data.object(forKey: "first_name") as? String
                       let lastName  = data.object(forKey: "last_name") as? String

                       if let email = data.object(forKey: "email") as? String
                       {
                           print(email)
                       }
                       else
                       {
                            // If user have signup with mobile number you are not able to get their email address
                           print("We are unable to access Facebook account details, please use other sign in methods.")
                       }
                   }
               }
       })
   }
   ```
2. In Objective C wire this code

   ```
   // START_LOADING;

   [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me"
                                      parameters:@{@"fields": @"picture, email,first_name,last_name"}]
    startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
    {
        if (!error)
        {
            if ([result valueForKey:@"email"] != nil)
            {
                NSLog([result valueForKey:@"email"]);
            }
            else
            {
               // If user have signup with mobile number you are not able to get their email address
              NSLog(@"We are unable to access Facebook account details, please use other sign in methods.");  
              //  STOP_LOADING;
            }
        }
    }];
   ```